# Permalink page to have different structure than loop — Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Can I customise a permalink page in WordPress? I've got HTML in the loop in that is fine for `index.php`.

However, I need to tweak what is actually seen on the permalink page. Is this possible in anyway?

Comment: You mean permalink to a `post` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by permalink page, I think you may have the wrong term. Here is an explanation of which templates to use though.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy